# ibeacon ranging in oin background output to second view controller

Tags: background-process, ibeacon

I'm working on a demo app with iBeacons. At this moment I have the ranging for the beacons working in my firstviewcontroller, when I want to show a detailed view of the beacon data in a second view controller I do hear the the audible feedback on beacon change which means the loop of detecting closest beacons is still running in view controller 1 ... but how can I get updates from view controller 1 in my second view controller?

I tried passing them in the segue, but then it is static NSString data, can anyone help me on how to get the "live" data in the second view controller?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process ranged iBeacon data in more than one ViewController, you can set up ranging in your AppDelegate, then call public methods on each ViewController from there.  The main didRangeBeacons: inRegion: in your AppDelegate can call the custom methods on each ViewController if that ViewController has been activated.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
    if (self.firstViewController != Nil) {
        [self.firstViewController handleBeacons: beacons];
    }
    if (self.secondViewController != Nil) {
        [self.secondViewController handleBeacons: beacons];
    }
}
```

In order to do this as above, you must maintain properties for each ViewController on your AppDelegate:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) FirstViewController *firstViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SecondViewController *secondViewController;

@end
```

You can populate them from each ViewController like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.firstViewController = self;
}
```